# Serializable Class Containing Sensitive Data

Tags: java, security, serialization, java-security

I had security scan on my project and got the following issue -

> Serializable Class Containing Sensitive Data

the solution is

> In Java, explicitly define final writeObject() to prevent serialization. This is the recommended solution. Define the writeObject() function to throw an exception explicitly denying serialization.

One of the issue it pointed in the scan :

```
Map<String, String> creditCardDetails;
```

I doubt if we can do this? We might actually require the object to serialize and pass over the network. I cannot do encryption. This might be costly in terms of time too.

Can we discuss on this for:

1. How to do this?
2. In what scenarios can we do this?
3. Any other solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

> I doubt if we can do this? We might actually require the object to serialize and pass over the network. I cannot do encryption. This might be costly in terms of time too.

If you pass customers' credit card details over an insecure channel, you are putting the customers at financial risk.  This is a *major breach of trust* and probably worse in many legal jurisdictions.

If your system is then found to leak credit card information, your customers are liable to sue you.  If the law suit goes to trial and you are found to have leaked credit card information due to a deliberate design decision, expect an award of *punative* damages against you / your company that well in excess of the actual damage to your customers.

There is only two safe solutions to this:

1. Use *strong* encryption when transmitting credit card information and other sensitive information.  The performance hit is a cost of doing business.  If the cost is too much, stay out of the business!
2. Don't transmit the credit card information.

Be aware that storing credit card details is potentially risky too.  That is also lawsuit territory if you get it wrong and there is a leak.

This is probably not what you / your bosses want to hear, but you / they need to hear it.

Comment: It is also a violation of your agreement with the credit card company.

Comment: Yeah, but you probably want to at least encrypt the whole stream rather than the odd object. Though you probably don't want to be using Java Serialisation at all.